# Moongose query with double WHERE statment

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am standing before a situation that I am new in Moongose and [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) as that, and I need to write something which will looks like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE case_id = $case_id AND calculation_id = $calculation_id;
```

This is how I have the statement right now in [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js):

```
app.get('/positions/:case_id/:calculation_id', function (req, res) {
    Positions.find()
        .where('case_id')
        .equals(req.params.case_id)
        .exec(function (err, records) {
            res.send(records);
        });
})
```

Adding a new .where really make no deal there, so what should I do?

Example row:

```
{"_id":"55e993ad29149e61931b826c","calculation_id":22,"case_id":"2","position_id":"33660","blockline":"B510L1 ","repairmethod":"20 ","guidenumber":"N/A ","amount":"6","hours":"0","starmutation":"N","text":"BLATNÍK P L V-Z","originalpartnumber":"","originalpartprice":"0","manufacturercode":"","quality":"","suppliercode":"","id":4},
```

So in this row, case_id = 2 and calculation_id 22.

If I open URL `positions/2/22`,

```
app.get('/positions/:case_id/:calculation_id', function (req, res) {
    Positions.find()
        .where('case_id').equals(req.params.case_id)
        .where('calculation_id').equals(req.params.calculation_id)
        .exec(function (err, records) {
            res.send(records);
        });
})
```

I get no result :(

Comment: I read this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html 
But didnt understand anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a second call to `where` with your additional criteria before you call `exec`:

```
.where('calculation_id')
.equals(req.params.calculation_id)
```

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks fo ranswer however it doesnt work for me. More details are in my EDIT above.

Comment: Have you verified that req.params actually has the values you expect? Also, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in the debugger on res.send(records); and inspecting err at that point. You may be getting an error and there's nothing in your code to handle that.

Comment: Try running a direct db query in the mongo console. Just to make sure your query is valid enough to get he result.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
app.get('/positions/:case_id/:calculation_id', function (req, res) {
Positions.find({case_id: req.params.case_id, calculation_id: req.params.calculation_id})
    .exec(function (err, records) {
        res.send(records);
    });
})
```

You should read the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/finding-documents.html).